# angular 2 material paginator get current page index

Tags: javascript, angular, pagination, angular-material2

I'am using material design with angular 2. I want to use material design paginator for my application and get the current selected page index in the component. There is not much documentation for the paginator plugin.here is the material paginator page: https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/overview

**html Code**

```
<md-paginator [length]="100"
              [pageSize]="10"
              [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
</md-paginator>
```

**angular 2 code**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'paginator-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'paginator-overview-example.html',
})
export class PaginatorOverviewExample {
   //I want to get page change event here
}
```

Comment: as i seen in his api https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api, there is @Output of page index

Comment: how can I implement that? how to get change event in paginator?

Comment: take a look at his example "pageEvent" is used https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/examples

Comment: yes it has pageEvent but How can that be use to get the page Index.

Comment: please put working demo, to help you better

Comment: I agree, Angular should give a better demo including a `onPageChange()` method.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get the current page index by using the `page` Output event. The `$event` from `page` returns three pieces of information:

- pageIndex
- pageSize
- length

html:

```
<md-paginator [length]="length"
              [pageSize]="pageSize"
              [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
              (page)="onPaginateChange($event)">
</md-paginator>
```

ts:

```
onPaginateChange(event){
    alert(JSON.stringify("Current page index: " + event.pageIndex));
  }
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/8van3R9RLJ1pJPIaWm28?p=preview)

Comment: How can we reset pageIndex to first page

Comment: hi nehal can you please check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51542796/table-angular-material-pagination-does-not-work-as-expected  ? I need help please

Comment: This answer saved my day. Thanks!