# Paginator changes index of datasource

Tags: angular, html-table, paginator

The sequence number of this table is determined by the index number of the array:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="table" aria-describedby="reviewScheduleTableDesc"
              id="table">
   <caption class="cdk-visually-hidden" id="reviewScheduleTableDesc">Review Schedule  Table</caption>
              <ng-container matColumnDef="sequence">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="table-header-cell" scope="col"> Sequence  </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index"
                  matTooltip="{{ i+1 }}"> {{ i+1 }} </td>
       </ng-container>`
```

and this is the code for the paginator:

```
<div class="paginator" *ngIf="this.reviewScheduleData.length > 3">
<mat-divider></mat-divider>
<div class="custom-paginator details-custom-paginator">
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[3]" [pageSize]="3"></mat-paginator>
</div>
</div>
```

in ts file:

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) set matPaginator(paginatorValue: MatPaginator) 
 {
   if (paginatorValue !== undefined && this.dataSource) {
    this.paginator = paginatorValue;
    this.dataSource.paginator = paginatorValue;
 }
}
```

When there is no paginator, all 8 items show as expected with the appropriate sequence number.
However, when there is the paginator, and it is on the 2nd pageindex, the sequence number is the same (index + 1) as the index of the array the paginator.

So the sequence numbers will 1,2 and 3 instead of 4,5 and 6 on the 2nd pageindex and that is incorrect.

[When I do not assign a paginator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFPPn.png)

[When I have a paginator and set to 3 items per page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiEyA.png)

How can I get the sequence number to 4,5, and 6 on the second page in the paginator?

I tried to assign a variable to the pageindex so I calculate it to show the right sequence number. For example, {{ i+1 + 3 * this.pageIndex}}. But I am not able to assign the pageindex to a variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Table angular material pagination does not work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51542796/table-angular-material-pagination-does-not-work-as-expected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a template reference variable to the paginator and use some like

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" ...>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="sequence">
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="table-header-cell" scope="col"> Sequence  </th>
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let i=index"> 
            {{i+1+(paginator?paginator.pageSize*paginator.pageIndex:0)}}
       </td>
    </ng-container>
    ....
</table>
    <!--see the templater variable reference: #paginator-->
    <mat-paginator #paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
                 showFirstLastButtons
                 aria-label="Select page of periodic elements">
    </mat-paginator>
```